# NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'template' on null object in Groovy

Tags: list, groovy

I got NPE with the following code. How to initiate the list properly? I want to iterate the list and use the value to create different names

```
class Comp {

private List<String> testSuite

Comp(List<String> testcase){
        this.testSuites = testcase
    }


    Job start() {
        for (String s : testCase) {
            Job.newInstance()
                    .withName("T/TESTS/"+ s)
        }
    }

    def testCase = [
            'name1', 'name2'
    ]
}

Comp.newInstance().start()
```

Comment: What is it `Job`?

Comment: Where did you get NPE ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think :

```
private List<String> testSuite = []
```

is enough and have no problem with this implementation.

Or you can do it in java way like shown below,

```
private List<String> testSuite = new ArrayList<>();
```